# How to pass name of temp table created in main sp to inner sp in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are sample tables

```
UserDetails : id,UserName,IsShow
Brand       : id,BrandName
Product     : id,ProductName
BrandProduct:id,brandid,productid,price
```

If Isshow is false, show entire price else hide second -fourth digit.(Price is 5 digits)

```
create procedure Sp_Details
@brandid int,
@productid int,
@IsShow bit
as
begin
    select SomeColumns
    into #tableForMechanism   
    from SomeData

    if @IsShow = 0 then
    begin
       select SomeColumns from #tableForMechanism  
    end 
    else
    begin
         -- Here want to pass table name created by this sp now
         -- So can check that table is exist.
         -- Because Inner sp is generic.From next 20 sp,have to call 
         -- same sp.That's why can't give same temp table name because
         -- their structure may be different

          exec innerDetailsProcedure 
    end          

end
go

create procedure innerDetailsProcedure
@tablename varchar(2000)
as
begin
    if OBJECT_ID(@tablename) is NULL    
    begin 
        raiserror('Table for mechanism is not created', 16, 1)
        return -1
    end
else
begin
      --update that table
       update @tablename
       set price = REPLACE(Price, (SUBSTRING(Price,2, 3*@Isshow)), 'xxx')
end


end
```

What is size of name of temp table created?How to fetch temp table created by this sp now for this session?

Comment: I can't see any temporary tables in your SP, what one are you refering to? (Temporary table names start with a hash (`#`)). Also, when you call the sp `innerDetailsProcedure`, you don't pass the value of scalar variable `@tablename`, however, it doesn't allow NULL values so the `EXEC` won't work. I'm afraid what your asking here is unclear. Can you reword your question to be more clear?

Comment: For temp tables, the stored procedure is compiled anew each time it's called. So it shouldn't matter if you're passing data in temp tables with the same names but with different structures.

Comment: `#tableForMechanism` is visible for any inner sp, if this flow and # name are persistent then you don't have to pass it as an argument - just use it inside inner sp.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ` is compiled anew` if there are prerequisites for that. For many cases recompilations are avoidable or their number can be reduced significantly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to inside a proc check if a #temp table exists, based on a table name that you have in a parameter to that proc? If so, see below. You have to prefix with the database name tempdb in your check with OBJECT_ID():

```
CREATE PROC p  @t1 sysname ,@t2 sysname AS IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + @t1) IS NOT NULL  PRINT '@t1 exists'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + @t2) IS NOT NULL  PRINT '@t2 exists' GO

CREATE TABLE #t(c1 int)

EXEC p @t1 = '#t', @t2 = '#doesntexist'
```